# Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix is a Gram matrix

Tags: matrices, inner-products

I showed that every Gram matrix, i.e. a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with $A_{ij} = \langle x_i,x_j\rangle$ where $x_1,...,x_n$ are vectors in an inner product vector space $V$, is Hermitian and positive semi-definite.

But how to show the converse: For every Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix there is a inner product space $V$ and vectors $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $\langle  x_i,x_j\rangle = A_{ij}$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every semi-definite matrix $A$ can be factored as $A=C^*C$ for some square matrix $C$. You can consider the columns of $C$ as your $x$'s.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps a lot!